# State Preservation and Restoration in SpriteKit

Tags: iphone, xcode5, sprite-kit

I am developing a game for iPhone which has one ViewController and multiple classes derived from SKScene that it switches back and forth between them. I have changed the app delegate and added following lines:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
```

However, sometimes when I press the home button and then come back to the app after, it starts from the beginning. The funny thing as I mentioned is this happens sometimes not always! I read the "State Preservation and Restoration" article on apple developers website and they mainly talk about saving different ViewControllers. Do I need to defined different ViewControllers for Scenes that I want to restore or is there an easy way to do this for Scenes (without saving everything in a file and reading the file again)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the paused property for SKView or SKnode. Simply pause your SKView or all your SKNodes when shouldSaveApplicationState is called.